# Transmit request from jsp to java

Tags: java, jsp

I've got a jsp file:

```
... import <%@ page import="classPath.ExampleClass" %>
 <% 
 ExampleClass cl = new ExampleClass(request); 
 %>
```

The Code of ExampleClass (Java):

```
private HttpServletRequest req;
public ExampleClass(HttpServletRequest req) {
    this.req = req;
}
```

So I want to receive the complete request to evaluate it in Java. But during deploying the following error appears:

```
Cannot process HttpRequest to Servlet
```

Why?

Comment: Are you working with a legacy app? If not, try to separate your logic from your view and use a MVC framework. Mixing JSPs and controller logic is considered bad practice

Comment: Which web server are you using? What exactly is the error, is it an exception? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with MVC framework? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Please add stacktrace

Comment: @user1860908 Please check [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/) or [SpringMVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not messup.Use of [implicit objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) of `JSP`

> JSP Implicit Objects are the Java objects that the JSP Container makes available to developers in each page and developer can call them directly without being explicitly declared. JSP Implicit Objects are also called pre-defined variables.

just write

```
 <% 
 ExampleClass cl = new ExampleClass(request); 
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create bean class like.

```
public class ExampleClass{          

      HttpServletRequest request;          

      public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
      }

      public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
      }    

    }
```

Now pass implicit `request` object with `jsp tag`

```
<jsp:useBean id="exampleClass" class="classPath.ExampleClass" scope="request"/>
 <jsp:setProperty name="exampleClass" property="request" value="${pageContext.request}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jsp add the following directive:

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="classPath.ExampleClass" scope="request">
    <jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="*" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="request" value="${pageContext.request}" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

The property "*" means that all attributes coming from the request will be set on the bean (class) e.g. form submission with various input fields.

The property "request" will set the HttpServletRequest as the last parameter so this method can be used as an indicator to start your logic.

Your class could look like:

```
public class ExampleClass {          

    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private String fieldValue;

    public void doLogic() {
        // do your controller logic here
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public String getFieldValue() {
        return fieldValue;
    }   

    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
        doLogic();
    }

    public void setFieldValue(String fieldValue) {
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }   

}
```

Notice that the property `fieldValue` is a custom field that you can add and can be set via form submission as mentioned above:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="feildValue" type="text" value="${bean.fieldValue}"/>
    <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```